# Google App Engine - code properly deployed, but incorrectly displayed

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml, google-cloud-datastore

I created a project in the google developer console and uploaded my code, that I have tesed before. Locally, everything worked fine, but on the server every request returned a 404 error and on '/' a mysterious page appeared. It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Cloud Datastore service</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Cloud Datastore service</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is no file in my code, that looks like this.

My app.yaml file:

```
application: swedenstream
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /[a-z-]*
  static_files: main.html
  upload: main.html

- url: /_content/events
  script: scripts/events.php

- url: /_content/article/.*
  script: scripts/article.php

- url: /_assets
  static_dir: assets
```

All my code files are properly uploaded and deployment didn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

The first handler in your app.yaml will match '/' and display the static file main.html.

Comment: It should. Main.html is a static webpage which uses css and js from _assets and dynamic content from _content and js history.pushState.

Comment: It seems that you have one version of the app that is not made default. Could you try making it the default?

Comment: Are you using push to deploy? looks like it's somehow done something wrong.  Go into your admin console, click on versions, click the radio button next to your version and click make default. For some reason it thinks that datastore builtin is your default version.

Comment: Yes, I have a connected GitHub repo. Do you mean the versionpage at compute->app engine->versions? I already tried that, but I received an error. I thought it's because I only have one version. I could try deploying a new version and making it the default.

Comment: Yes! I solved it. I think it was a bug in the new developer console (console.developers.google.com). Now I was on appengine.google.com and made my version the default there.